# Color, bold in part of text in matplotlib (using LaTeX), with pdf output?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, colors, latex

I am creating a figure to be saved as PDF using matplotlib in Python.
(Only) the first letter of the figure title needs to be bolded and a specific (custom) color.  Minimalistically, I would assume the following would work (non-custom color):

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(1,1)
ax.set_title(r'{\bf\color{red} A}: absquatulate')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

But it doesn't.

One can instead (I can't find the reference) go to much more trouble, using PGF backend, to get some color, but this fails when the `r'\bf'` is used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pgf_with_latex = {
        "text.usetex": True, 
        "pgf.rcfonts": False, 
        "pgf.preamble": [
            r'\usepackage{color}', 
            r'\definecolor{colorB}{rgb}{ 0.1, 0.5, 0.999 }'

                ]
    }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(1,1)
ax.set_title(r'{\bf\color{colorB} A}: absquatulate')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

How do I get the \bf\color to work simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the following works (Use `\bfseries`, and I find it requires separate nested braces):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import FigureCanvasPgf
matplotlib.backend_bases.register_backend('pdf', FigureCanvasPgf)

pgf_with_latex = {
        "text.usetex": True, 
        "pgf.preamble": [
            r'\usepackage{color}', 
            r'\definecolor{colorB}{rgb}{ 0.1, 0.5, 0.999 }'

                ]
    }
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
plt.plot(1,1)
plt.title(r'{ \textcolor{colorB} {\bfseries A}}: absquatulate')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly updated version from CPBL's [elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253805/9035706).
The main difference is that newer versions of Matplotlib want to get `pgf.preamble` as on string, not a list of strings.
Also, seems that `text.usetex` is already `True` by default.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import FigureCanvasPgf

matplotlib.backend_bases.register_backend('pdf', FigureCanvasPgf)

matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.preamble": r"""
            \usepackage{xcolor}
            \definecolor{colorB}{rgb}{ 0.1, 0.5, 0.999 }
            """
})

plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
plt.plot(1, 1)
plt.title(r'{ \textcolor{colorB} {\bfseries A}}: absquatulate')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```